# Power BI - Incorrect City locations

Tags: powerbi

I have a single table that is similar to below:

| State | City | Zip | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alaska | Anchorage | 12345 | $105,593 |
| Alabama | Montgomery | 23593 | $20,493 |
| Vermont | Burlington | 58395 | $121,503 |

I've created a basic map in Power BI and added State, City, and Zipcode to a hierarchy which I've added as the 'Location' for the map visual. The problem is that when I "expand" to the City level, it plots Burlington as a city in the UK, but I want to specify that the data is referring to the city in the US. How can I do this?

Notes: this is the only table in my Power BI file and it comes from an Excel sheet, which I can edit if needed.

Comment: I have found that plotting a map by city name is terrible to get right. I've switched to using lat-long of cities (You can find whole excel sheets online!). If you data set is small I would suggest making a small table with this data and if its big find your dataset online.

Comment: Plotting at the zipcode level seems to work fine, but there are too many records at that level.... I was considering getting lat/longs for the cities, but didn't find any tables online with exhaustive lists of US cities (most sites only have "major cities")... might be the best way to go, but it will likely involve a lot of manual data clean up/manipulation

Comment: Maybe plotting on zipcode is different for US based cities than for Dutch based cities (I have found that it oftentimes doesn't work at all!). I agree that it might take a lot of time to do manual clean-up, but once you have a file you are good to go! However, I had a website a while ago where you could buy these lat-long files for $10, which where mega extensive (Had all cities for the Netherlands), I'm sorry I don't know the name anymore..